# CSS - menu column bumping down footer when using expanding panels in menu, want footer up with content column

Tags: css

PROBLEM SOLVED - thanks everyone!!! :)

Here is the site: http://ratestsite.com/ecc/index2.php

What I want is; the footer to stay like a loyal dog at the foot of the content div - while the sidebar (expanding menus) grows or shrinks. :)

I'm still green to css, I promise I've tried and I'm still trying. Floats, Z-indexes, hidden... I'm ready for a drink. ;-)

Thank you and much much, many much, good computer Karma to you for even reading this. :)

Comment: What is the unwanted behavior? Can you also be a little more specific with what you would like to happen?

Comment: the first think I thought about is floating the sidebar right and not left

Comment: I think what he want's is the footer to "touch" the red-border box, instead of being "pushed" down by the sidebar

Comment: Also by the way, when you're laying things out, if you use `outline` in place of `border`, it won't take up pixel space and throw off your design.

Comment: She - thats what she wants, and Patrick Evans gave the fix.  Thanks all! :)

Comment: You can't believe I was using those UGLY borders for 'design', LOL - silly I just wanted to clearly see where the divs were with out having to fuss with Firebug.  :)

Comment: @KBarnes, I know that.  But when you set a 1px border all the way around just to visualize the edges during the design process, your element is 2px wider and higher.  Set a 3px border (like you did for your container) and the element is 6px higher and larger.  What I'm saying is that if you use `outline: 2px solid red;` instead of `border: 2px solid red;`, the red border won't _take up any space_ and therefore your element will render at the actual size it is supposed to be in the end-product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put ur content and footer both into a seperate div and leave the sidebar out. then float both the seperate div and the menu div.

example

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="ContentContainer"> <!-- should get  float: left  style
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar1"></div>  <!-- should get float: left style
    <br style="clear:both; height:0px;"> <!---- used to make sure the parent div expands with content, it wont otherwise with floated elements
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - thank you - thank you - thank you - thank you - thank you - I shall not bleed from my eyes any more today - THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 1):

Set your footer to `clear:none;` instead of `clear:both;`

Comment: Since I assumed you didn't want your footer div inside the content div, this will give you what you want.

Comment: Good catch @tnypxl, but WHOAH!, try it in firebug, and things go nuts!  There's something flawed with this design...

Comment: Well, I'm sure he'll work it out. Sometimes solutions lead to more problems. It's a process for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.sidebar1 { float:right; }` and moving it *inside* of the content div.

Comment: And make `margin-left` 35px instead of 22px

Comment: Nevermind, use the margin thing only if you aren't moving it inside the content.

Comment: Unless I a missing something - I put the <sidebar1> inside the <content>, changed the float to right, and this is what I get.  http://ratestsite.com/ecc/index3.php  (the footer still drops)

Comment: no, don't move the sidebar inside the content, I think he meant move the footer inside the content but idk. Or you could use the margin-left I posted earlier.

Comment: Well, not technically. If @JCOC is right, and you are wanting the footer to attach to the bottom of the content box, that's exactly what's happening (check the red line).  Is this what you want it look like: http://jmc-creative.com/tmp/Clipboard02.jpg ?